# How to perform nested read using XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml

Due to memory requirements I have to use `XmlReader` to process xml files, so I am new to this class. Before I bake something unusual, how to perform a nested read using XmlReader?

What I mean, I am in the middle of xml file, at some node `<p>` -- I would like to read no further than to closing `</p>` to this very `<p>` I mentioned.

This "nested read" (i.e. read which does not go any further) is useful when using recursive call to some processing functions. Normal `Read` would continue up to end of the file.

Comment: Have you seen the [`ReadSubtree` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper too many `Read...` ;-) I missed it, thank you very much, could you post your comment as an answer (so I could accept it).

Comment: Done, with a little extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`ReadSubtree` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - that method treats the current element like a document of its own, for which an `XmlReader` is returned. After closing that reader, your original reader will be placed after the closing tag of the read element.

One remark about your question:

> Normal `Read` would continue up to end of the file.

Well, not automatically so, but you're right that one needs to take some care not to overshoot the closing tag, and there is no way to ensure that other components will not do so when passing the original reader.

And one caveat when using `ReadSubtree`: The new reader will *not* point to the opening tag of the element initially, it will point to the position right before the opening tag. Therefore, after invoking `ReadSubtree`, you normally first want to call `Read()` once on the subtree reader.

Comment: Thank you once again for added details!